# Tips on how to extract Apple firmware for a Broadcom Wireless chip, using binwalk or a similar tool?

Tags: firmware-analysis, memory-dump, driver

**TLDR: I have a dump of my wireless chip's RAM, but am having trouble separating firmware from, possibly the driver itself, from the nvram configuration portion.**

So, I'm trying to enhance the performance of my wireless chip (bcm43602 chip on a macbookpro14,3) while running Linux. The current brcmfmac firmware, mixed with a mishmashed nvram.txt are doing a pretty decent job on the wifi side, not so much on the bluetooth side.

So, I wanted to take a shot at getting the proper firmware Apple themselves ship. I began by looking at the macOS kext that drives the chip and inside it found several sections that look like firmware. I was then playing around with the wireless diagnostic tool on macOS, when I realized that among other things, it created a dump of the chip's RAM.

I decided to take a look at that file, and compared it with several brcmfmac firmwares and the beginning of the files are virtually identical, which tells me that the firmware is indeed in that RAM dump.

My issue is that I don't know where the firmware actually ends. The brcmfmac files all end with version strings, but it's not so clear on the Apple images (there are some references to version and revision, but I'm not sure they actually mark anything)

An idea I had was to look for the interception of the macOS driver and the RAM dump(which might work, IF the firmware is entirely loaded in contiguous memory, of course); I did this in a very naive way by comparing byte by byte, until a difference was found. This method gave me a file that's roughly 276 kb, smaller than most firmware images. And further, taking a second look in an hex diff, I noticed that after the end of my extracted file, there are minimal differences between the RAM and the driver file, after which comes another identical chunk that must be roughly another 100 kB. That is to say, I haven't really progressed much.

I've now been looking into whether binwalk might be able to help me get a better approximation at what might actually be a complete valid image, but I find I don't really know how to use it or what most of the detected signatures actually mean in the context of what I'm trying to do.